# Why is Parse Query Adapter always empty?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to fill a list with parse query adapter but it is always empty. I am following the tutorial provided by parse (https://parse.com/tutorials/parse-query-adapter). Please tell me if I am doing anything wrong. How can I make it work ? Thank you

```
public class BrandsFragment extends Fragment {
 private ParseQueryAdapter mainAdapter;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter(getActivity(), "Brands");
    mainAdapter.setTextKey("BrandName");
 }

  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_brands, container, false);

    ListView listFollowingView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.brands_list);
    brands_list.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
    mainAdapter.loadObjects();

    if(mainAdapter.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"EMPTY",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 }
}
```

Layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.swipeit.swipeit.BrandsActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/brands_list" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: 1) Have you tried setting up a simple query for "Brands" and post the results to logcat. Just as a debugging step, could be a matter of ACL preventing the query or the like. 2) from the code you posted it looks like `brands_list.setAdapter(mainAdapter)` should be `listFollowingView .setAdapter(mainAdapter)` 3) do not think it is a source of problem but `mainAdapter.loadObjects()` should not be needed as ParseQueryAdapter has autoload set to true by default 4) the check `mainAdapter.isEmpty()` should always resolve to true because the adapter has not yet have time to fetch the results.

Comment: Thank you for your points. 1) I have many queries for 'Brands' and they all work. 2) yes you are right, I forgot to rename ListView to brands_list in the above code. 4) If you say it will take time to fetch the results, then how can I make it dynamic so it loads the view automatically? I waited for few minutes but nothing shows up.

Comment: Well it should definitely not take minutes but rather a short 1-3 seconds (as for normal queries). My point was just that the check is performed in a matter of nanoseconds after the adapter has been set, and a network query is not that fast. Next attempt: add this code `mainAdapter.addOnQueryLoadListener(new ParseQueryAdapter.OnQueryLoadListener() {...})` this gives u a chance to see if the adapter is loading objects and simply not showing them.  A second thought, try moving `mainAdapter.setTextKey("BrandName")` to the bottom of `onCreateView`

Comment: @user2709885 Well, what's the difference between this query and the other ones? Try to compare them. And are you sure your layout is set up properly? Anyway, I second cYrixmorten: use `mainAdapter.addOnQueryLoadListerer()` and if what's returned (if anything).

Comment: @cYrixmorten LigamentThrasher. Thank you for your reply. I used mainAdapter.addOnQueryLoadListerer() and I printed the loaded  Parse objects in log. I am getting all the logs with the right parse objects but it is still not updating the list view. What could be going wrong ?

Comment: Also in mainAdapter.addOnQueryLoadListerer(), method onLoading() does not work but onLoaded works perfectly fine ?

Comment: Can you please post the layout? :)

Comment: @LigamentThrasher I updated the layout in the main question above.

Comment: I cannot think of nothing else than "BrandName" not being a valid String column?

Comment: I rewrote all the code and it started working. However, thank you for all your help.